# Using some objective priors (for unbounded space) in a Metropolis-Hastings MCMC

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, objective-bayes

I'm doing some simulations using a M-H MCMC, and I was thinking of using some objective priors for some parameters. These parameters must be in $\mathbb{R}^+$. I was thinking of using $\pi(\theta)\propto 1$.

Are there any inconveniences? Should I take care with some possible issue?

Comment: First inconvenience, make sure your posterior is a proper distribution.